# Is it possible to have too many methods in terms of stack size and possible overflow?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, stack, stack-overflow

We all know that it's good practice to create small methods that promote reuse, which inevitably will cause lots of methods being placed on the stack.  However is it possible to reach the scenario where there are so many nested methods calls that a [StackOverflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx) Exception occurs?

Would the accepted solution to be simply increase the stack size?

The [documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx) that a such an exception will occur during "very deep or unbounded recursion" so it certainly seems possible, or does the .NET framework dynamically handle stack size for us?

My question can be summed up like so:

> Is it possible to have such a well designed program (in
>   terms of small reusable methods) that is becomes necassary to increase the
>   stack size and hence use more resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. I just did a very quick test, and a StackOverflowException occurs after 15,000 nested calls.

There's no way you'll be writing code that will non-recursively nest 15,000 times due to the sheer number of methods you have.

Obviously the exact number depends on many function-local variables you have allocated on the stack. But whatever that actual number may be, it is nowhere near enough to do what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET stack size is fixed, and 1 MB by default.

> Is it possible to have such a well designed program (in terms of small reusable methods) that is becomes necessary to increase the stack size and hence use more resources?

It will not be in the decomposition of your logic into methods.

The only way you'll encounter a Stack Overflow that is not a direct bug is with recursion. And when that happens (threatens), don't increase the stack but rewrite the code to use a different way to store data (like a `Stack<T>`).

Answer (score 0):

In the managed world the stack has a special role for performance. If you manage to allocate something on the stack (using primitives or structs) you don't have to put it on the heap. Allocating on the heap adds GC pressure which on average slows the program.

So I could image a program which is faster by allocating lots of stuff on the stack. Even using **stackalloc** (which is a less well known feature of C#/the CLR).

There are valid cases to do this. They are rare. Just saying "there are no valid uses" is plain wrong.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi - I agree, this isn't what I was asking

Comment: @m.edmondson, can you elaborate on what you want to know? I answered the question that you posed in the last paragraph: Are there valid reasons to program in such a way that require increasing stack size. I gave reasons for that. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @usr - My question was regarding having so many methods that the stack size must be increased (hence using more resources).  There was nothing asking about where objects are stored (stack or heap) but rather the method pointers that will always be on the stack.  Hence heap storage is irrelevant to the scope of the question.